# No GUI install Grub Customizer 14.04

Tags: grub2

Don't see Grub Customizer in system tools and can't start using gksudo

Terminal command line paste:

```
user@LC2530Sb:~/Desktop$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
[sudo] password for user: 
 This PPA contains the latest release of Grub Customizer.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp9qs8jevh/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp9qs8jevh/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 3F055C03 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp9qs8jevh/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 3F055C03: public key "Launchpad PPA for Daniel Richter" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
user@LC2530Sb:~/Desktop$
```

Why can't I start Grub Customizer?

Comment: you added the PPA, but you still have to run `apt-get update` and install the program.

Answer (score 0):

Did you type

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo install grub-customizer
```

If so you've done everything right search for it in the search bar on ubuntu and it should come up.

Comment: Did you do these things?  Is it working?

Answer (score 0):

After installing, start it by typing:

```
grub-customizer &
```

on an X terminal. It will take care of showing you the *gksudo* prompt. When it's started, you can pin it to the dock using right click on its dock icon (Unity, Cairo-dock, Docky...).

On my Ubuntu 14.04.1, Grub-customizer does not put its icon in System Tools. Anyway, it does work.

If it still does not work on your system, you could also check that you don't have a `SEG_FAULT` error when starting it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 14.0.4 - 64 bit. this is how you need to install this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

and then issue this to invoke this:

```
sudo grub-customizer
```

It's working fine for me on two machines.